# SCPI OPC command not working

Tags: oscilloscope, python, scpi

I am writing a SCPI script in Python for the Siglent SDS1104X-E. I have been banging my head for a few days trying to get this to work. Below is my main py file:

```
    
    ################################################################################
    #     Set the Scope IP address and Port number
    ################################################################################
    SCOPE_IP_ADDR = "192.168.1.220"
    SCOPE_IP_PORT = 5025
    ################################################################################
    #     Useful Variables
    ################################################################################
    channel_list = [1, 2, 3, 4] # The values in this list correspond to the 4 channels on the scope.
                                  
    channel_1_dict = {'enable': 'True', 'bandwidth': 'ON', 'coupling': 'D1M',
                      'volt_div': 1, 'volt_offset': 0, 'probe_attenuation': 1}

    sc.config_chan(channel_list[0], channel_1_dict['enable'], channel_1_dict['volt_div'],
               channel_1_dict['volt_offset'], channel_1_dict['coupling'],
               channel_1_dict['bandwidth'], channel_1_dict['probe_attenuation'])

    sc = sds.SDS1104X_Object(SCOPE_IP_ADDR, SCOPE_IP_PORT)
    sc.open_connection()
    sc.reset_inst()
    print(sc.get_id())
```

My problem is that the reset command (*RST) does not happen fast enough. When configuring multiple channels, it does not always set all of the channels.

Below is a snip from the object that sends the actual commands

```
    def reset_inst(self):
        self._send_cmd("*RST")

    # helper functions
    def _send_cmd(self, cmd):
        """ send cmd if connected, no resp """
        if self.connection.is_connected:
            self.connection.write(cmd)

    def _send_qry(self, cmd):
        """ send cmd if connected, return resp """
        if self.connection.is_connected:
            self.connection.write(cmd)
            return self.connection.read_raw()
        else:
            return None
```

The only way I can get this to work is to use the Python "sleep" command after every SCPI command

```
    time.sleep(3)
```

The programming manual says to send the *OPC query in order to wait for a command to finish:

[image]

I guess I could just put these hard delays everywhere in my script but it seems really clunky and not the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*RST causes the entire scope to reset.  It doesn't send a response before the reset, and it can't send one afterwards - the reset causes it to "forget" everything that happened before the reset.

The [programming guide](https://siglentna.com/USA_website_2014/Documents/Program_Material/SIGLENT_Digital_Oscilloscopes_Remote%20Control%20Manual.pdf) tells you when a command will send a response.  A command with a response will have a block named "RESPONSE FORMAT" in its description.

What you want to do is to send the "*RST" then periodically ask if the scope is ready to talk to you.

The examples in the guide start with asking for the device identification using the "*IDN?" command.

Send your "*RST" then a short pause (hundred milliseconds or so) then send the "*IDN?" command.  Repeat the pause and the "*IDN?" command until you get a good response.

When you look at other commands, take note of whether or not they send a response.  If they don't, then you will have to find a different way to see if they succeeded.

For example, the "*RCL" (recall) command doesn't provide a response.  If you want to load a particular bunch of settings you have to send the "*RCL" then check the status of the "EXecution error status Register"  (command "EXR?") to see if it worked properly.

Comment: I edited my question because I see that I had actually pasted in my code incorrect. I am actually sending IDN? after the RST. I do the RST as an initial clearing of everything when the script first runs. Excuse my ignorant question, but how do I check the execution status register. There doesn't seem to be a command for that.

Comment: Oh, I see, we are looking at different manuals this is what I am looking at [manual](https://int.siglent.com/u_file/document/SDS1000%20Series&SDS2000X&SDS2000X-E_ProgrammingGuide_PG01-E02D.pdf). I will go over the commands in your manual and I will let you know what I figure out.

Comment: Apologies for overloading your comment, just a quick update. I am actually using the allstatus command ALST?, and that seems to be a workaround. My channels and trig get set. The problem is that there are multiple manuals floating around online. So now on to the next problem. hahaha.

Comment: Yeah, ALTS? gets you all the registers.